# Compress json sting in jquery and Decompress in php

Tags: php, json, post, compression

I have a table with almost 10,000 record and I need post the table content on the server to create a PDF file. So what i did is i get all record and save that in json string format and post to a server to process a PDF file. It is working if the record is less than 3,000 but if the record is more than 3,000 the data that I post is empty. That is maybe too large of data that i post. Is there other way to **compress the json string in jquery** before i post it in server and **decompress the string in server side (php)** or if there another way to do this. This is my  phpinfo();

```
post_max_size   190M
memory_limit    100M
max_file_uploads    20
max_execution_time  30
```

Comment: it shouldn't be hard to split up your posts into chunks...beyond that I would need to know more about what your doing to provide an answer.

Comment: I dont solve this. But what i did is create temp txt file that i append the data json string until its done. Then ill get that file from the server and use that as json data to make a pdf then delete the file after i get the json string. And its work hehehe